# ERROR in Sitecore EXM marketing automation: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: exm, marketing-automation

Trying to create a simple custom token to add on my email campaign. After following this documentation from Sitecore, again I encountered an error.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/create-a-custom-personalization-token.html#UUID-17d8830e-578b-971d-6421-15aa1bfce543_id__Create_a_custom

In marketing automation, Im trying to select an email campaign and encountered this error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.EmailCampaignsController\r\nGet on type Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.EmailCampaignsController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception doesn't seem to be related to the custom tokens. What is says is that the application can't decide which action of `EmailCampaignsController` to call. Could you please check in the browser, how many requests are going to `https://{yoursite}/sitecore/api/exm/campaigns/automated?cultureName=en&sc_site=shell`? Also, if you open this URL in your browser, do you see a JSON array with email campaigns?